# Buttons in JFrame, access to methods in AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have `Table` which extends `JPanel`, `MyTableModel` extends `AbstractTableModel`. I want to add in JFrame  button  `ActionPerformed` and invoke `deleteRow()` from `MyTableModel` on selected row.  How should I do it ?

EDIT:

when I add button in Frame from Palette and I add from context menu on button

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String text1 = titleTextField.getText();
    String text2 = authorTextField.getText();
    int text3 = Integer.parseInt(yearTextField.getText());
    JTable table = table1.getTable();
            MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();

            System.out.println(text1 + text2 +text3);
            model.addRow(new Book(model.list.size(), text1, text2, text3));
}
```

I get Null Pointer Exc on   -> 
JTable table = table1.getTable(); -> returning null

UPDATE 3:

MainFrame

```
    package net.kxyz;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import net.kxyz.Table.MyTableModel;
    import xyz.libary.Book;


 public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public MainFrame() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    initComponents();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    titleTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    authorTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    try {
        table1 = new net.kxyz.Table();
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    butt1 = new net.kxyz.Butt();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    yearTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    deleteButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Title:");

    jLabel2.setText("Author:");

    jLabel3.setText("Year:");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout butt1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(butt1);
    butt1.setLayout(butt1Layout);
    butt1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        butt1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    butt1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        butt1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 150, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jButton1.setText("Addddd");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    deleteButton.setText("DELETE");
    deleteButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            deleteButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(table1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(107, 107, 107)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                                    .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                        .addComponent(authorTextField)
                                        .addComponent(titleTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                            .addComponent(jButton1))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addComponent(yearTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))))
                        .addComponent(butt1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(deleteButton)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(deleteButton)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(titleTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(authorTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(yearTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                    .addComponent(butt1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(table1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 329, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(0, 64, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String text1 = titleTextField.getText();
    String text2 = authorTextField.getText();
    int text3 = Integer.parseInt(yearTextField.getText());
    JTable table = table1.getTable();
    MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();
    System.out.println(text1 + text2 + text3);
    model.addRow(new Book(model.list.size(), text1, text2, text3));
}

private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JTable table = table1.getTable();
    MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();
    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
    System.out.println("ROW: " + row);
    model.removeRow(row);
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JTextField authorTextField;
private net.kxyz.Butt butt1;
private javax.swing.JButton deleteButton;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private net.kxyz.Table table1;
private javax.swing.JTextField titleTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField yearTextField;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Table Panel

```
  /*
   * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
   * and open the template in the editor.
   */
  package net.kxyz;

  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.GridLayout;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
  import xyz.libary.Book;
  import xyz.libary.DataInterface;
  import xyz.libary.MockDataInterface;


  public class Table extends javax.swing.JPanel {

JTable table;
MyTableModel model;

public JTable getTable() {
    return table;
}
MockDataInterfaceImpl dataInterface = new MockDataInterfaceImpl();

public Table() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    super(new GridLayout(1, 0));
    final ArrayList<xyz.libary.Book> list = dataInterface.getAllBooks();
    model = new MyTableModel(list);
    jTable1 = new JTable(model);
    jTable1.setLayout(null);
    jTable1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    jTable1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable1);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(163, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = {"ID", "Title", "Author",
        "Year", "State"};
    ArrayList<Book> list = null;

    MyTableModel(ArrayList<Book> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    MyTableModel() {
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public void removeRow(int row) {

        list.remove(row);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

        Book object = list.get(row);

        switch (col) {
            case 0:
                return object.getId();
            case 1:
                return object.getTitle();
            case 2:
                return object.getAuthor();
            case 3:
                return object.getYear();
            case 4:
                return object.isState();
            default:
                return "unknown";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }
    boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
        false, true, true, true, true,};

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit[columnIndex];
    }

    public void addRow(Book e) {
        list.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {



        switch (col) {
            case 0:
            // id not editable  list.get(row).setId((int)value);
            case 1:
                list.get(row).setTitle((String) value);

                break;
            case 2:
                list.get(row).setAuthor((String) value);
                break;
            case 3:
                list.get(row).setYear((int) value);
                break;
            case 4:
                list.get(row).setState(value);
                System.out.println("VALUE: " + value);
                break;

        }
        System.out.println("UPDATE ROW: " + row + " COL " + col);
        dataInterface.updateBook(list.get(row));
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
}
 }
```

Book

```
package xyz.libary;


public class Book {
int id;
String title;
String author;
int year;
Boolean state;

public Book() {};
public Book(int id, String title, String author, int year) {
    this.id = id ;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
    this.state = true;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public Boolean isState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(Boolean state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public void setState(Object value) {
    this.state=(Boolean)(value);
}



}
```

Butt, I dont use

```
  package net.kxyz;


 public class Butt extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form Butt
 */
public Butt() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

MockDataInterfaceImpl

```
 package net.kxyz;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import xyz.libary.Book;

 public class MockDataInterfaceImpl{

 ArrayList<Book> book = new ArrayList<>();

public MockDataInterfaceImpl() {

    book.add(new Book(book.size(), "TYTUL", "Autor", 1232));
    book.add(new Book(book.size(), "Ogien", "Mickiewicz", 2012 ));
    book.add(new Book(book.size(), "Woda", "Mickiewicz", 2012 ));
    book.add(new Book(book.size(), "Ziemia", "Mickiewicz", 2012 ));
    book.add(new Book(book.size(), "Powietrze", "Mickiewicz", 2012 ));
}


@Override
public ArrayList getAllBooks() {
     return book;
}

@Override
public void updateBook(Book book) {
    int index = book.getId() ;
    this.book.get(index).setTitle(book.getTitle());
    this.book.get(index).setAuthor(book.getAuthor());
    this.book.get(index).setYear(book.getYear());
    this.book.get(index).setState(book.isState());
    System.out.println("Updated id = " +index);
 }

@Override
public void deleteBook(Book book) {
    int index = book.getId() ;
    this.book.remove(index);
    System.out.println("Remove id = " +index);
    }

@Override
public void addBook(Book book) {
    this.book.add(book);
    }

 }
```

Comment: `Table` cannot be compiled without the `Book` class

Comment: Same with `Butt` and `DataInterface`. That is why I created my own code in the first place

Comment: Since to failed to make you code compilable, I'm going to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I don't see an `actionPerformed` method anywhere in your code, I am going to assume you don't know how to add the code in NetBeans (because some parts are uneditable). That would be just foolish of me to assume that you have no idea how to program event code ;-) So here is the basic steps in Netbeans

1. Right-click on the button that you want to perform the action on.
2. Select `Event -> Action -> actionPerformed`
3. You should see something like this generated in your source code near the bottom

   ```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

   }
   ```
4. Enter your code in that method for deleting the row

---

Also it looks like your `JTable` and `TableModel` are in different class than the buttons. What you need to do then is to have a getter for the table in the `Table` class. After you have that, you can do something like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    JTable table = table1.getTable();
    MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)table.getModel();
    model.removeRow(...);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Tested it myself, with shorter code. It works fine. Not ClassCastException

Table.java

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Table extends JPanel {

    JTable table;

    public Table() {
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello"},
            {"Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello"},
            {"Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello"},
            {"Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello"}};

        table = new JTable(new MyTableModel(data));
        add(new JScrollPane(table));

    }

    public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private String[] columnNames = {"ID", "Title", "Author",
            "Year", "State"};
        Object[][] list;

        public MyTableModel(Object[][] list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return list.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return list[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

TestTable.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import practice.Table.MyTableModel;

public class TestTable extends JFrame {

    private Table table1;
    private JButton button;
    public TestTable() {
        table1 = new Table();
        button = new JButton("Get Value at 0, 0");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTable table = table1.getTable();
                MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)table.getModel();
                System.out.println(model.getValueAt(0, 0));
            }
        });

        add(table1);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTable();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i know it, I dont have access   table1.deleteRow(row);

Comment: Look at the second part of the answer

Comment: I get Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: net.kxyz.Table$MyTableModel cannot be cast to net.kxyz.MyTableModel

Comment: did you make the getter in the `Table` class `return table;`?

Comment: yes,  public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }

Comment: Run the code from my **UPDATE**. It works fine for me. No ClassCastException

Comment: Your code work with button manually created, I have problem with layouts (table,labels,textfields,buttons) so I create buttons and all others from Netbeans pallete, but when I want to add action for button I have NullPointerExc, I have edited main post with code

Comment: Ask another question. do not edit one that has already been answered

Comment: I didnt edit my earlier post, I edit to add one more question, your code after update work with manually created button, but when I add button from Netbeans palette I have NullPointerExcp on MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();

Comment: The only way you're going to get a `NullPointerException` on that line is if `table` is null. Or you're reading the wrong line where the exception is pointing to.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at net.kxyz.MainFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:223)
 at net.kxyz.MainFrame.access$100(MainFrame.java:23)
 at net.kxyz.MainFrame$2.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:144),     223 is           MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();

Comment: Do you know what a `NullPointerException` means?

Comment: Yes, table1.getTable() -> returning null

Comment: If you can't figure it out by looking at your own code, use a debugger. That's what its for. Put a breakpoint at that line.

Comment: 1) I don't know what you did differently. 2) I can't compile your code to test it.

Comment: Ok give me maybe 30 minutes then I'll have time to look at it

Comment: I also have question, how to add method which will periodic check book status and if status changed it alert, with RCP ?

Comment: 1) What am i supposed to do with your application to reproduce this exception? 2) I will not answer your second question. This site is not a help desk. You ask a question, get an answer, then move on to the next question. I am already doing a lot by even helping you with exception, as it is not related to original question posted, but rather a new question based on changes you made to the original code.

Comment: 1) select row and use delete button, or add new book 2) I understand

Comment: It's giving you a `NullPointerException` because the `JTable` you are using is the one you drag and dropped, `jTable1`, not the `table` above your constructor. So you should make `getTable()` `return jTable1`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean removeRow(int), how about -

```
jbutton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      table.deleteRow(row);
   }
});
```

Comment: i dont have access to table.deleteRow() because this method is in MyTableModel